# Can I ask MCQ-related questions on Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

1. What is the difference between Chemistry and Meta Chemistry on Stack Exchange?
2. On which website should I ask about MCQs (multiple choice questions)?

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta

Comment: Chemistry.SE is a site to ask questions about chemistry. Meta.Chemistry.SE is a site to ask questions about the site Chemistry.SE.  What is MCQ?

Comment: Ok thanx got it.. If i am having difficulty in a question which is a multiple choice question.. How should i ask it? Or should i ask it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to copy/paste an MCQ question - you clearly arn't getting the concept of a question and answer site.

Step back, take a look at how *well received* questions are formed - focus on specific answerable *chemistry* problems, rather than the immediate "what's this answer to a question i had" .

You can sometimes frame a question in the *context* of a question in a paper, but far too many folks just copy it.

So, the answer is *neither*. However it might be worth reading through the question you have, trying to work out what you *specifically* do not understand and try to frame that. Don't give them your options, focus on the *specific* steps of problem solving you don't understand.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a concrete chemistry question which is posed as a multiple choice question, you can indeed post it on [Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/). But, and this is a general policy on all Stack Exchange search, *include the research you have done*. Stack Exchange sites are Q&A sites and not 'quiz' forums. If you don't do this, you risk your question to be heavily downvoted.

[Meta Chemistry](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/) is not a site for a different 'type' of Chemistry questions; rather, for [questions *about* the Chemistry site itself](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta).